# Does Docker execute the entrypoint when a container is used in a multistage build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If define a multistage `Dockerfile` like so:

```
FROM exampleabc:latest
COPY app.go .


FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Would the `exampleabc:latest` have it's entrypoint executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> Only the last ENTRYPOINT instruction in the Dockerfile will have an effect.